# IF-statements containing OR in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, paste

I have a DF. If the 'name1' column is not blank or not contains a specific value (e.g. christopher), I would like to paste some info. If the column contains a blank value or 'christopher' I would like these values to be maintained.

I have tried with different if-else sentences combined with OR, none of them lead me to the desired result. Because the names in the DF can differ, I am looking for a %like%-solution or similar and not an exact match (except from the blank values)

```
df <- data.frame("name1" = c("august", "", "christopher", "david", "erica", ""), "name2" = c("berit", "august", "david", "erica", "frank", "christopher"), stringsAsFactors = F)

#IF-ELSE sentence with '%!like%'
'%!like%' <- function(x,y)!('%like%'(x,y))
df$name1 <- ifelse(df$name1 !=''  |  df$name1 %!like% ('christopher') ,paste('Something to be pasted'), df$name1)

#Nested IF-ELSE sentence with '%!like%'
df$name1 <- ifelse(df$name1 =='', '', 
       ifelse(df$name1 %!like% ('christopher') | df$name1 !='' , paste('Something to be pasted'),
       ifelse(df$name1 %!like% ('christopher'),df$name1))
```

My expected result is

```
df_exp <- data.frame("name1" = c("Something to be pasted", "", "christopher", "Something to be pasted", "Something to be pasted", ""), "name2" = c("berit", "august", "david", "erica", "frank", "christopher"))
```

Comment: Paste is useful for sticking things together, e.g., `paste("a", "b")` gives `"a b"`. If you only have one thing, `paste('Something to be pasted')` is a long way to write `'Something to be pasted'`.

Comment: I know, It was just to make the question look less boring 

Comment: No need to complicate your question unnecessarily. It distracts from the real issue which is your logical statements.

Comment: I think maybe you want `&` not `|`? Let's talk through what you are accomplishing with `felse(df$name1 =='', '', 
       ifelse(df$name1 %!like% ('christopher') | df$name1 !=''` First, if the name is blank, it stays blank, okay. Next, if the name is not like Christopher *or* if it is not blank, then it becomes `'Something to be pasted'`. Why are you checking not blank `!= ''` in the second `ifelse()` - all the blanks have already been captured by the first one. And because of that, everything left isn't blank, so `xxx | df$name1 != ''` will always be true whatever `xxx` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this slight changes on your code. Using `grepl()` produces logic values that can be better understood in other functions:

```
#Data
df <- data.frame("name1" = c("august", "", "christopher", "david", "erica", ""), "name2" = c("berit", "august", "david", "erica", "frank", "christopher"), stringsAsFactors = F)

#IF-ELSE
df$name1 <- ifelse(df$name1 =='', '', 
                   ifelse(grepl('christopher',df$name1)==F & df$name1 !='' , paste('Something to be pasted'),
                          df$name1))
```

Output:

```
                   name1       name2
1 Something to be pasted       berit
2                             august
3            christopher       david
4 Something to be pasted       erica
5 Something to be pasted       frank
6                        christopher
```